# OnTextChangedListener EditText android app behaviour problems

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listener

To summarize, I have a `listview`, each item in the listview has a `button`. Buttons can be in two states : highlighted or not highlighted. I also have a `edittext` at the bottom of the screen which contains a stake and textviews used to display the result.  Each `button` text contains a double; when the button is in the highlighted state, the stake is multiplied times the double on the button and the result is displayed in the textview. If multiple buttons are highlighted, the result is the stake * all the highlighted buttons. The result changes dynamically when the stake is changed by the user; which is done using the code below and the onTextChangedListener. When the user first enter's the stake and then makes his selections, everything works perfectly fine. However, my issue is that when the user FIRST makes the selections with the edittext empty and AFTER enters the stake into the edittext there is no reaction; the user must then reselect all his choices for the system to work properly. I am looking for suggestions on how to alter the below code to fix this issue and make the app behave in the same way, regardless of whether the stake is entered first, or the selections are made first. The method below is executed when any of the buttons in the listview are clicked. The editText we are concerned with is the variable `mEdit`. The rest of the code is not as relevant to the issue but I included it to avoid confusion.

```
  @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v;
                Button b = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.oddsbutton);
                ListView listView = (ListView) layout.getParent();
                final int position = listView.getPositionForView(listView);
                String buttontext = b.getText().toString();
                Button lastchance = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.oddsbutton);
                TextView betidtextbox = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gid);
                String betid = betidtextbox.getText().toString();
                TipDisplayer currentwriter = alltips.get(position + 1);
                Log.d("new", newBet.toString());
                if (ids.contains(Integer.parseInt(betid))) {
                    b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    b.setTextSize(18);
                    ids.remove(new Integer(Integer.parseInt(betid)));
                    Log.d("new", newBet.toString());
                    currentwriter.toggleHighlighted();
                    //checkhighlight(layout);
                    Log.d("getodds", buttontext);
                    selection = "home";

                    TextView teamss = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.teamstxt);
                    String teams = teamss.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("teams", teams);
                    TextView bet = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.bettxt);
                    String bettxt = bet.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("btxttext", bettxt);
                    newBet.generateoddstesting(betid, buttontext, false, teams, selection, bettxt);
                    double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                    TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                    TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                    myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                    EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    if (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        stake = 0.00;
                        newwinnings = 0.00;
                        potentialWinnings.setText("0.00");

                    } else {
                        mEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                          int count, int after) {
                            }

                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                      int before, int count) {
                                if (s.length() != 0) {
                                    stake = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                                    double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                                    newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                                    TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                                    TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                                    myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                                    potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                                    newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();

                                } else {
                                    stake = 0.00;
                                    newwinnings = 0.00;
                                    double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                                    TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                                    TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                                    myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                                    potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                                    newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();

                                }
                            }

                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            }
                        });
                        //stake = Double.parseDouble(mEdit.getText().toString());
                        newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();


                    }
                } else {

                    ids.add(Integer.parseInt(betid));
                    //checkhighlight(layout);

                    b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EB102E"));
                    b.setTextSize(20);
                    currentwriter.toggleHighlighted();
                    selection = "home";
                    String getodds = lastchance.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("getoddsss", getodds);
                    EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    if (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        stake = 0.00;
                        newwinnings = 0.00;
                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                        potentialWinnings.setText("0.00");
                    } else {
                        mEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                          int count, int after) {
                            }

                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                      int before, int count) {
                                if (s.length() != 0) {
                                    stake = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                                    double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                                    newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                                    TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                                    TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                                    myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                                    potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                                    newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();
                                } else {
                                    stake = 0.00;
                                    double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                                    newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                                    TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                                    TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                                    myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                                    potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                                    newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();
                                }
                            }

                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            }
                        });
                        stake = Double.parseDouble(mEdit.getText().toString());
                        TextView teamms = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.teamstxt);
                        String teams = teamms.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("teams", teams);
                        TextView bet = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.bettxt);
                        String bettxt = (String) bet.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("bettxt", bettxt);
                        newBet.generateoddstesting(betid, buttontext, true, teams, selection, bettxt);
                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                        newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();


                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: This is really confusing.

Comment: Just pay attention to the listener attached to the `mEdit` variable, the rest isn't really relevant